# TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2 enable simultaneously

Tags: tls

We have a web front end server with TLS 1.0 enabled for web application in IIS.

This WFE communicates internally with external workflow manager server through fqdn and TLS 1.0

If we enable TLS 1.2 in WFE server, will the communication break between WFE and external workflow manager?

Can we have simultaneous support for TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have simultaneous support for TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2.

Which one will actually be used will depends on the other end too.

Configuring 1.2 everywhere will make it work with 1.2 but you can also let 1.0 be on just in case you missed a device that still uses 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure every SSL/TLS endpoint, to accept different versions of SSL/TLS. Therefore your WFE can support TLS 1.0 and 1.2 simultaneously.